# Divide a string into 3 equal sized substrings C++

Tags: c++, string, replace

I need to take a string and divide it into 3 equally sized substrings. Each substring has a length of 10, and the last character in each substring is '|'. I'm not sure how exactly to do this without moving the | over to the right. The current code I have for the first line is below

```
line1 = "          |";
line2 = "          |";
line3 = "          |";`

if (someString.length() < 0 && someString.length() > 9);
{
    for (int i = 0; i < someString.length(); i++)
    {
        line1.replace(0, i, someString.substr(0, i));
    }
}
```

However, this isn't working well. If someString is "foo", the console will print `Bi` and move my | over 2 spaces. The reason i used .substr is because .at and [] threw me 
"invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’"

Can someone help me out? I feel pretty lost

Comment: That `if` condition? Um. When will that *ever* be true? How can `someString.length()` be *both* less than zero *and* greater than nine *simultaneously*?

Comment: What are `line1`, `line2`, and `line3` defined as? Do you have a minimum working example, instead of a code snippet which cannot even compile?

Comment: I don't understand the question. How can the substrings always be length 10? Shouldn't they be `someString.length()/3`?

Comment: Don't you need three strings for output or a string array/vector size 3?

Comment: How can the length of a string ever be less than 0?

Comment: What if the original string has 20 characters?  How could you divide this evenly by 3?  Or is the string always 30 characters and/or the number of characters in the string always evenly divisible by 3? I think you need to explain in better detail what you're trying to do.

Comment: Shouldn't your argument to replace and substring be i * 10?

Comment: @WhozCraig that one's a typo, it should be || instead of &&. Also should be someString.length() > 0, I do it because i dont want any weird behavior with strings that haven't been assigned a value yet.

Comment: @willkill07 line1 is supposed to show the first 9 characters of the string, plus the |, line 2 is supposed to show the next nine plus |, and then line 3 is supposed to show the last nine plus |

Comment: So.. it shouldn't be the posted code? Ok.

Comment: @Barmar In the program that I'm making, they need to be length ten

Comment: You shouldn't have `;` at the end of the `if()` line. That gives it an empty body, and the next block isn't conditional.

Comment: @bruch Am I missing something? Isn't it just `line1 = someString.substr(0, 9) + "|"; line2 = someString.substr(10, 9)  + "|"; line3 = someStrinng.substr(20, 9) + "|";`?